# Reference request for believing there are no sages who can see beyond the physical world

Tags: sutras, physicality, divine, eye, clairvoyance

Originally thought it was among some of the list of downfalls but couldn't find it there. I remember hearing somewhere in the suttas perhaps the unskillfulness of believing there are no sages who can see beyond the physical world. Ring any bells? (Oops on the vagueness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pali suttas refer to disbelieving the sages know 'this world' ('loka') & 'the other world' ('paraloka'). The term 'world' ('loka') does not necessary refer to physical worlds. For example, AN 4.45 refers to the world arising & ceasing within the mind.

> For it is in this fathom-long carcass with its perception and mind that I describe the world, its origin, its cessation, and the practice that leads to its cessation.
>
> [AN 4.45](https://suttacentral.net/an4.45/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

The reference you are seeking is a stock phrase; found in MN 60, MN 117, AN 10.211 and at least [15 other suttas](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=no%20ascetic%20or%20brahmin%20who%20is%20rightly%20comported), as follows:

> i. The Doctrine of Nihilism ([natthikavāda](https://suttacentral.net/define/natthikav%C4%81da?lang=en))
>
> Householders, there are some recluses
> and brahmins whose doctrine and view is this: ‘There is nothing given,
> nothing offered, nothing sacrificed; no fruit or result of good and
> bad actions; no this world, no other world; no mother, no father; no
> beings who are spontaneously arisen; no good and virtuous recluses and
> brahmins in the world who have themselves realised by direct knowledge
> and declare this world and the other world.’
>
> [MN 60](https://suttacentral.net/mn60/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

[MN 117](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false) clearly says the above doctrine sides with merit (goodness) & attachment; thus does not lead to liberation & Nibbana.

Comment: Yes!! This is it! Wild how so many modern day materialists and those into Scientism as their religion (in a manner of speaking) fit pretty much into this same camp of nihilism although more limited specifically to claiming: 'no other world . . . no beings who are spontaneously arisen; no good and virtuous recluses and brahmins in the world who have themselves realised by direct knowledge and declare this world and the other world.' ...which could make one wonder how it got that way and how limited they are even in their nihilism although maybe they think math and tech are a more expanded trap

Comment: The "materialists" are actually those who believe this verse refers to rebirth or reincarnation

Comment: How so Dhamma Dhatu?

Comment: There's a good talk about the view of Materialism from Ajahn Punnadhammo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSCjbzJCCuk

Comment: The Buddha never used any term to mean "materialism". The only place I have found the term "materialism" found is in the Nikaya commentary called the Patisambiddhamagga, which literally says "rebirth is materialism" and "non-rebirth is non-materialism".